# preg_replace function doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

I have the following code :

```
<?php
$test = "BEGIN_SESSION 7
1h+ 47
30mn-1h 20
15mn-30mn 16
5mn-15mn 43
2mn-5mn 29
30s-2mn 35
0s-30s 170
END_SESSION";

preg_match("/BEGIN_SESSION(.*)END_SESSION/is", $test, $matches);
$session = $matches[0];
preg_match('/30s-2mn ([0-9]{2})/ms', $session, $matches); 
$a = $matches[1];
preg_match('/0s-30s ([0-9]{3})/ms', $session, $matches); 
$b = $matches[1];
var_dump($session);
$session = preg_replace('/30s-2mn ([0-9]{2})\n0s-30s ([0-9]{3})/ms', "0s-2mn " .   ($a+$b), $session);

var_dump($session);
?>
```

I would the function to display `$session` like this :

```
"BEGIN_SESSION 7
1h+ 47
30mn-1h 20
15mn-30mn 16
5mn-15mn 43
2mn-5mn 29
0s-2mn 205
END_SESSION"
```

But instead it doesn't change anything! What's the problem with my code?

Comment: Can i ask how you get this data?

Comment: It would be much easier to change the code that generates string $test, otherwise it seems that you are band-aiding the original code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexes are making a lot of assumptions, and that's not good. Regexes are supposed to remove the need for assumptions, but you assume there will be two digits in the 30s-2mn row, and you assume there will be three digits in the 0s-30s row, and most cripplingly, you assume that `\n` is used to delimit new lines, rather than maybe `\r\n` or any arbitrary trailing whitespace on the line.

Regexes don't really seem suitable here. I'd suggest parsing it instead:

```
$newline = "
"; // cheating way to handle the newline problem :p
$lines = explode($newline,$test);
$results = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(" ",trim($line),2);
    if( count($parts) < 2) continue;
    else {
       $results[$parts[0]] = intval($parts[1]);
    }
}
// now do your conversion:
$results['0s-2mn'] = $results['0s-30s'] + $results['30s-2mn'];
unset($results['0s-30s'],$results['30s-2mn']);
// now get the result
$session = "BEGIN_SESSION ".$results['BEGIN_SESSION'].$newline;
foreach($results as $k=>$v) $session .= $k." ".$v.$newline;
$session .= "END_SESSION";

var_dump($session);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic PHP syntax:

```
$session = preg_replace('/30s-2mn ([0-9]{2})\n0s-3 etc....');
                                            ^^---
```

`\n` newlines are NOT intepreted as newlines by PHP within `'`-singlequoted strings. That's seen by PHP as a literal backslash and a literal `n`, not as a newline.

Use `"`-quoted strings instead.